# Magento - getCustomer() giving unexpected results

Tags: customer, customer-session

I am experiencing some odd results when using Magento's

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

I have the below code to first check if the customer is logged in, and if so to get the firstname of the logged in customer:

```
if(!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn())
{
    $name = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getFirstname();
    print 'Hello '.$name;
    // ...
}
```

Most of the time this works fine and if `Joe Bloggs` is logged in then it outputs:

```
Hello Joe
```

But every now and then, and it seems to be when a high amount of customers are logged in I get unexpected outputs with other names

```
Hello Lucy 
or
Hello John
```

Is `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()` a foolproof way of getting the customers details or is it possible it's getting another logged in customers details? Or have I got a problem with my sessions mixing up?

Comment: In what file you check the customer name?  Is it a controller, observer or anything else?

Comment: What are you using for session storage?

Comment: having looked into this more it was down to the full page cache on my store. A mix of making the relevant pages non-cached or hole punching blocks it now seems to have down the trick